# How can I model my MongoDB database to allow me to easily add in new products & user interactions?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I am looking for the best way to model this scenario:

There is a ProductA model. Users can "like" or "dislike" ProductA documents. The documents are then added to an array in the User model called "likes" & "dislikes."

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...,
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductA' }],
    dislikes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductA' }],
    ...,
});
```

Now, I have realized that I want to add in a new Product: "ProductB." How do I restructure this database to keep this scalable and allow me to add new products? I am not sure what the best way to do this would be in MongoDB.

I believe my ideal scenario is the following psuedo-model:

```
var InteractionSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    product: // anonymous reference to an object
    productType: //enum of which product it is
    user: // user who made the interaction
    interactionType: // like or dislike enum
});
```

I could not find any reference to how to handle anonymous references in MongoDB however. I would appreciate some advice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can have three collections at a time:

1. products (contains all the products)
2. users (contains user information)
3. user_product_likes (contains user's like/dislike)

Respective schema can be,

```
UserInformationSchema : 
{
    name : {
      type: String,
      required: false
      ..
      },
      ..
}

ProductSchema : 
{
    product_type : {
      type: Integer,
    },
    ...
}

InteractionSchema :
{
     product_id : {
       type: Integer
       required: true
    },
     user_id : {
       type: Integer
       required: true
    },
    like : {
       type: Boolean
       required: false,
       default:false
    },
    dislike : {
      type: Booelan,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
}
```